# Still have INVALID redirect_uri for linkedin hello.js after having authorized the correct domain

Tags: javascript

Still having INVALID redirect_uri issues after having updated and authorizing the website.  They are identical-- the one  in my code and he authourized OAUTH2.0 linkedin developer myapps.  Using hello.js.    Any advice?

```
hello.on('auth.login', function(r){
  // Get Profile
  hello.api(r.network+':/me', function(p){
    document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = "<img src='"+ p.thumbnail + "' width=24/>Connected to "+ r.network+" as " + p.name;
  });
});


hello.init({
  'linkedin' : '**********',
},{
   redirect_uri:'https://www.********'
});
```

Comment: I should also mention this is on a chrome extension

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that the website you are redirecting to must be written exactly the same in both places and many urls wont work.  Can't explain as to why these websites won't work at the moment but its a start.

Comment: redirecting to https://www.google.com and https://www.example.com worked but obviously thats not where we want to be redirecting.